# Volvos with the same parts as the Volvo 440 GL with 2 liter motor?

Tags: exhaust, volvo-440

I have an old Volvo 440 GL (~1994) and I need to find a part to the exhaust system that costs the same amount as the car itself if bought from the Volvo company itself: this is the [flange part](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/8054/3252) in the exhaust system with 6 bults, not 4 as in some Volvos. So now I am trying to find out which Volvos have the equivalent parts as the Volvo 440 GL. Volvo 240, 460 and with which motor? I have heard that even Volvos with 440 GL but different motors use different parts. The information would be very useful in waiting for old parts to get separated from accident cars, having automatic old part monitoring setted on like [here](https://www.avk.fi/fi/paivystaja/purkuajoneuvot?v=2).

> So how can I find which Volvos have the same parts as the Volvo 440 GL with 2.0 liters motor?

Comment: Your "440" must be a Scandinavian only model? Not even finding parts for it here in the States. Here in the states, many parts like this can be made by a muffler shop without too much of an issue. Way back when while working at a wrecking yard, we used a book made by Hollander (I believe) which showed all of the compatibility between models. I would bet all of this is located online now, though.

Comment: @Paulster2 I am not sure whether this kind of service `"muffler"` exist here. The Hollander manual looks to be targeted only to cars in States. I tried to find an app/book for it to read it in my phone but did not find anything. Good idea though, perhaps something like that may exist here also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you'll find any other Volvos that share the same downpipe as the 440 - If I remember correctly it is a transverse engine front wheel drive, whereas other Volvos of that era (300, 700 and 900 series) were all longitudinal engine rear wheel drive, so the exhaust layout will be totally different.

You're probably better off looking for a cheaper aftermarket exhaust system, or seeing if the current one can be repaired.